# How to check if there is a new version of google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a google chrome extension and i want to check every X minutes if there is a new version.
And if there is a new version i want to update the extension automatically.

Thanks!

Comment: All extension is automatically updated when there is a new version available

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome automatically performs these checks and updates the extension automatically, every few hours. See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/autoupdate for more info. As noted there you can also use `--extensions-update-frequency` command-line flag to set a more frequent interval in seconds.